# silverlight and textwrapping

Tags: silverlight

So here I am trapped in a nightmare of trying to make text wrap in silverlight.  I have text intermixed with links.  LIke this:

text text text link text text text link

It needs to wrap.  I've tried things like textwrapping and wrap panels but I just can't get it right.

Any ideas on how to do this?  My only idea is to split up the text of the textblock into seperate textblocks for each word and put it into a wrap panel.  Not easy!

I read about runs and textblocks.  Do runs have an onclick event?  What can I do to make the text wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Runs" are a part of a set of objects provided by the `System.Windows.Documents` namespace that comes with Silverlight 4 and are displayed in a `RichTextBox` control.  These objects do not raised events themselves.

However if you are able to use SL4 then the `RichTextBox` may well be the right control for you.  It has a `Hyperlink` element that, whilst not raising events, does carry `Command` and `CommandParameter` properties for MVVM stylie interaction (or you can simply assign a URI).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like HtmlTextBlock.

See the article here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2007/09/24/bringing-more-html-to-silverlight-htmltextblock-improvements.aspx

Hope it helps